New node rebuild failed with error "Unexpected disk state: failed to read transaction log"
We are doing cassandra datacenter migration. We are following the below steps for that.

Restrict traffic to the existing datacenter.
Expand the Cassandra cluster by adding a new datacenter.
Rebuild the newly created datacenter.
Switch traffic over to the K8ssandra datacenter.
Decommission the original Cassandra datacenter.

But when I do nodetool rebuild --dc1, it streaming data from datacenter dc1 to dc2 for sometime and later fails with this error.
ERROR [main] 2024-07-09 10:41:39,489 LogTransaction.java:548 - Unexpected disk state: failed to read transaction log [me_txn_compaction_86392750-3dcc-11ef-a93a-479fdd5ff0c8.log in /opt/cassandra/data/data/kdev_anom_tsdbuid/name_to_uid-f6d49340989c11edbced35afea1d8f39]
Files and contents follow:
/opt/cassandra/data/data/kdev_anom_tsdbuid/name_to_uid-f6d49340989c11edbced35afea1d8f39/me_txn_compaction_86392750-3dcc-11ef-a93a-479fdd5ff0c8.log
    ADD:[/var/lib/cassandra/data/kdev_anom_tsdbuid/name_to_uid-f6d49340989c11edbced35afea1d8f39/me-112-big,0,8][437472153]
    REMOVE:[/var/lib/cassandra/data/kdev_anom_tsdbuid/name_to_uid-f6d49340989c11edbced35afea1d8f39/me-107-big,1720513410543,9][1106468096]
    REMOVE:[/var/lib/cassandra/data/kdev_anom_tsdbuid/name_to_uid-f6d49340989c11edbced35afea1d8f39/me-88-big,1720506432414,9][761473640]
        ***Unexpected files detected for sstable [me-88-big-]: last update time [Tue Jul 09 03:27:32 UTC 2024] (1720495652098) should have been [Tue Jul 09 06:27:12 UTC 2024] (1720506432414)
    REMOVE:[/var/lib/cassandra/data/kdev_anom_tsdbuid/name_to_uid-f6d49340989c11edbced35afea1d8f39/me-95-big,1720513410622,9][3156590260]
    REMOVE:[/var/lib/cassandra/data/kdev_anom_tsdbuid/name_to_uid-f6d49340989c11edbced35afea1d8f39/me-89-big,1720506454683,9][1749318440]
    COMMIT:[,0,0][2613697770]

ERROR [main] 2024-07-09 10:41:39,489 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - Cannot remove temporary or obsoleted files for kdev_anom_tsdbuid.name_to_uid due to a problem with transaction log files. Please check records with problems in the log messages above and fix them. Refer to the 3.0 upgrading instructions in NEWS.txt for a description of transaction log files.

Can someone help me understanding how this could happen and how to resolve this. I do not see this SST files in source/target datacenter anywhere though.

In Cassandra 3.0, transaction logs were introduced (CASSANDRA-7066) to replace the functionality previously provided by the compaction log table (system.compactions_in_progress). The transaction logs list the SSTables involved in compactions.
Another way of putting it is that the transaction log shows the ancestors of an SSTable. Looking at the output you posted as an example, the following SSTables were merged into me-112-big:
me-112-big
  - me-107-big
  - me-88-big
  - me-95-big
  - me-89-big

But the transaction couldn't be committed because there was a problem with one of the SSTables (me-88-big).
My suspicion is that the node hit a race condition and the SSTable didn't get written to disk completely. Is it possible that the stream got aborted or interrupted mid-flight during the rebuild?
If you look closely at this log entry:
        ***Unexpected files detected for sstable [me-88-big-]: \
          last update time [Tue Jul 09 03:27:32 UTC 2024] (1720495652098) \
          should have been [Tue Jul 09 06:27:12 UTC 2024] (1720506432414)

it states that SSTable me-88-big- has a last update time of 03:27:32 (timestamp 1720495652098) but it was expecting it to be 06:27:12 (timestamp 1720506432414) which indicates that the file is incomplete.
The second error states that you need to look at the C* 3.0 NEWS.txt for details on transaction logs and how to resolve the issue.
You'll need to find out if me-112-big-* exists in the data/ directory mentioned in the log. If it does, you should delete its ancestors (the SSTables listed with REMOVE:).
You'll need to do a bit of analysis using the instructions in NEWS.txt to determine what to do next. Cheers!
